# Using MathCaptcha in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, captcha

I am running MVC5 and am trying to implement CAPTCHA in my web application. I installed CaptchaMvc.Mvc5 (version 1.5.0) and when I try to use the HTMLHelper in my View, it is giving me a red squiggly for this `@Html.MathCaptcha()` helper method.

The error says "HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'MathCaptcha' and no accessible extension method 'MathCaptcha' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any pointers could be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the Visual Studio after you install CaptchaMvc nuget package and reopen it. That should fix the issue.